# How to $http Get call with identifer

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I need to make a get call with a id as the identifier. I have only done this with Angular resource, not $http. I am new to understanding how $http works with angular.

Angular Controller

```
  $scope.EmailPdf = function () {
    $http.get('/api/Pdf/{id}').success(function () {
        $scope.PrintPreviewModal();
    });
}
```

Routing

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name:"PdfApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new {controller = "apiGeneratePdf", id=RouteParameter.Optional}
        );
```

api controller

```
      public string Get(int id)
        {
        JobDataAdapter adapter = new JobDataAdapter();
        Job job = new Job();
        job = adapter.GetJob(id);
        if (job == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        try
        {
```

Error Message

```
{"$id":"1","Message":"The request is invalid.","MessageDetail":"The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.String Get(Int32)' in 'TexasExterior.Controllers.PdfController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."}
```

Updated
Web Config

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "PdfApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/pdf/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "PdfController", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Controller

```
$scope.EmailPdf = function () {
    $http.get('/api/Pdf/', { id: id }).success(function () {
        $scope.PrintPreviewModal();
    });
}
```

Error Message

> ReferenceError: id is not defined

Controller

```
 var id=1    
$scope.EmailPdf = function () {
    $http.get('/api/Pdf?id=id').success(function () {
        $scope.PrintPreviewModal();
});
```

}

Error Message

> {"$id":"1","Message":"The request is invalid.","MessageDetail":"The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.String Get(Int32)' in 'TexasExterior.Controllers.PdfController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."}

Controller

```
var _id = 1;
var URL = '/api/Pdf';
$scope.EmailPdf = function () {
    $http.get(URL, { id: _id }).success(function () {
        $scope.PrintPreviewModal();
    });
}
```

Error Message

```
{"$id":"1","Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:44301/api/Pdf'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'Pdf' that matches the request."}
```

Comment: You wouldn't use the template syntax, {id}, here in the javascript code. Presumably the id is locally available to the script in which case you just want something like "$http.get('/api/Pdf/'+id).success(function () {"

Comment: The error message is pretty descriptive, you're not passing in anything for id, try this: `$http.get('/api/Pdf/'+id)`

Comment: HTTP Error 404.11 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence.

Comment: looks like a security issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
  $http.get(URL,{id:id})
```

That is pass in your params as the second argument to the get call as a map or string.

Comment: $http.get('/api/Pdf/', { id: id })

Comment: ReferenceError: id is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Your `id` is not defined

PdfController

update your config routes to:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name:"PdfApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/pdf/{id}",
        defaults: new {controller = "PdfController", id=RouteParameter.Optional}
        );
```

otherwise you can use different syntax ie:

```
 var id=1    
 $scope.EmailPdf = function () {
    $http.get('/api/Pdf?id=id).success(function () {
        $scope.PrintPreviewModal();
    });
}
```

or

```
 var _id=1;   
 var URL='/api/Pdf' ;
 $scope.EmailPdf = function () {
   $http.get(URL,{id:_id}).success(function () {
        $scope.PrintPreviewModal();
    });
}
```

UPDATE

```
var _id=1;   
var URL='/api/Pdf/' ;
$scope.EmailPdf = function () {
    $http.get(URL,{id:_id}).success(function () {
        $scope.PrintPreviewModal();
    });
}
```

Error Message

```
$id: "1"
 Message: "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:44301/api/Pdf/'."
   MessageDetail: "No action was found on the controller 'Pdf' that matches the request."
```

Other Option

```
  var id=1    
$scope.EmailPdf = function () {
    $http.get('/api/Pdf?id=id').success(function () {
        $scope.PrintPreviewModal();
});
}
```

Error Message

```
{"$id":"1","Message":"The request is invalid.","MessageDetail":"The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.String Get(Int32)' in 'TexasExterior.Controllers.PdfController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."}
```

Comment: @user3913120 what is the name of your api controller ?

Comment: @user3919120 please see top of my answear update your config.Routes

Comment: k, i have updated my post with the different with error messages

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I needed was

> public string Get(int id=1)

the code i originally posted did not need to be changed. thanks though